# How to create a color tinted black and white effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

I was wondering how I would go about recreating this look on a photo using Photoshop?

[image]

Comment: **step 1:** greyscale  **step 2:** colorize

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way to create an effect like that with precise control is using a Gradient Map.

Start with a normal colour image.

[image: No Gradient Map]

If you apply a Gradient Map Adjustment Layer on top, with a pink to black gradient, the effect will be identical to what you're after. It even means you can choose precise colours for anywhere along the tonal range. I'm a big fan of Gradient Maps.

[image: Gradient Map]

---

**Pros**

- Precise
- Quick
- Editable afterwards
- Can be saved as a gradient and applied to other documents quickly

**Cons**

- None :)

Answer (score 2):

Since the text in the cropped image implies this was part of a larger design, it is possible that a layout program was used. As an alternative to colorizing the image in Photoshop (which is the question as asked), I would typically do this using a greyscale image (not "color" nor "RGB" nor "CMYK"). After placing it in the layout, one can then select a background color for the image using the color swatches.

This makes it easy to adjust the color based upon the document specification and use a single image with multiple colors (such as different colored chapter header decoration etc).

Note that the foreground color can also be adjusted independently with this method, but one typically needs to have the "content tool" selected (rather than the "box/window tool")

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways. An easy one is to put the photo on one layer, desaturate it to make it black and white, then create a new layer above. Fill that layer with fuchsia and set it's blending mode to 'multiply'.

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods, but I would change the photo to greyscale first using the (Image>Adjustments>Black and white) filter. Then, open (Image>Adjustments>Photo filter) and change the adjusting color to the color and intensity that you desire.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to convert the image to a duotone color mode.

If you're starting with a CMYK or RGB image, you'll first need to convert it to grayscale (discard color information).

Then choose Image > Mode > Duotone.  Now choose one of the magenta presets in the duotone options dropdown.

Save and done!